# How to optimise the url for search engines?

Tags: php, url, search-engines

I have a php template which has one `index.php` and all the different pages (`content1.html`, `content2.html`, etc) are shown on the `index.php`page. So for example I can open `www.example.com/index.php?content1` and it will show the `content1.html`.

Now what I would like is this: often you see websites where the URL is like: `www.example.com/this-is-the-content`.  I know how to do this with an exclamation mark like `www.example.com/?content1` where you just don't write the `index.php`.

But how can I make a URL name, which is completely different from the filename? For example, `www.example.com/this-is-some-page` would show me the content of index.php?content1

Answer (score 3):

You probably should look into `mod_rewrite` which could help you out.

[See this cheat sheet for some help](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: ok thanks to you 2, this would work for static pages. But what about page names which are dynamically created and stored in a mysql database. Say for example I create a new page index.php?newpage and I save the url name of the page in a database. Now the htaccess would have to connect to the database to get the url name wouldnt it?

Btw stackoverflow is doing exactly what I want to achieve, look at the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524908/how-to-optimise-the-url-for-search-engines

Answer (score 3):

.htaccess is definitely one route you could go for rewriting URL's. But, I think that the piece you're missing is the part where you should store your page's content in a database or store the file names and URL slugs of the pages in an array on index.php to pull from. This way you can have a different URL slug than the actual file name.

For instance, if you use a rewrite rule in .htaccess that says all requests for the URL `http://www.example.com/the-page-you-want` need to display the content from content1.html, you will need to specify somewhere that 'the-page-you-want' refers to content1.html.

Answer (score 1):

refer to @Pål Brattberg's answer for detailed description

@phpheini You don't need to bind the .htaccess file to the database, suppose if you want the URL for your article like

```
http://example.com/sports/45/world-cup-2011.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*?).html$ /index.php?type=$1&article_id=$2
```

Here $1 and $2 get the article type and article_id which can change. index.php can output content based on the parameters.